# How to send geofences array to another activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, geofencing, android-geofence

So I have geofences which I fetch from firestore and add them to a list of geofences. I want to send this list from my logIn activity to my main activity so the geofences will be activated then. 
How do I send my geofences array to my main Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass an Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) to your main Activity. If you need to put custom objects (such as your geofence info) in the Intent, [make your custom class implement Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 0):

first you will need to create a model to store data geofence such as: `data class Geofence ()`

Then in your start activity:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("GEOFENCES", geofences)
        startActivity(intent)
```

Access that intent on next acitivy:

```
val geofences = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Geofence>("GEOFENCES")
```

Remember your Geofence model have anotation @Parcelize

Hope this help!